# iOS not loading next level

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm aware that having a large initial level in Unity causes the iPhone/iPad to shut down the app before it is done loading. The solution, I thought, would be a loading level that yields for 1 or 2 frames and then proceeds to load the next level.

```
functon Start()
{
    yield;

    Application.LoadLevel(1);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work for some reason. Both scenes are setup correctly in the build window of Unity, and in Xcode no errors occur.

Anyone have any suggestions that I may persue?

Comment: I've used this technique in the past and it definitely does help on devices that load slower (iPhone 3g and lower).

Answer (score 1):

`functon` is not a valid keyword here.

Assuming that this is a cut & paste mistake, make sure of the following things:

- you have at least two scenes in your build settings
- it works in the editor (load the scene 0 in the editor and press play)
- you've added your script to an object in the scene '0'

Also, I suggest using scene names instead of scene index when calling `Application.LoadLevel`.

For example, you could have a scene called "Preload" and another called "Menu".  Your "Preload" scene would be the first one in your build settings.  The call would then be:

```
Application.LoadLevel("Menu");
```

Which is less error-prone if you reorganize the order of the scenes in the build settings, especially once your project starts getting bigger.

Comment: @yoma All great advice indeed, but all of which i sadly already applied prior to posting ;( And it wasn't a copy/paste mistake, i just typed it out here. Not sure why it isn't loading on the device. works fine in the editor. No errors in xcode either. I am using WWW in the other scene to get a tweet feed, perhaps it's that.